# Can't load Flowdocuments with xml entites from textfile

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

i doing a project with the wpf richtextbox control. I'm saving the textfile with the xamlwriter class.

When i'm trying to load the file everything is working really well except if there are html entities in the file. Because the overloaded XamlReader class only excepts a stream or a XmlReader, the html entities ( in this case '<' (`&lt;`)  and  '>'  (`&gt;`) are expanded and loaded into the xamlreader where an exception occurs because it thinks '<' is an empty node.

Are there any known workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't the `XamlWriter` saving these entities as entities?

Comment: The problem was that the xmlreader already expanded the entities and handed them over to the xamlreader who thought > or < is an opened or closed tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. got it. Loaded the xaml as a stream like so:

```
 public FlowDocument Load(string path)
    {
        using (StreamReader sReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(path))
        {
            using (Stream s = sReader.BaseStream)
            {
                return (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(s);
            }
        }
    }
```